# Django RestFramework: Serializers very slow with large instances at the same time

Tags: django-rest-framework, backend

I'm crawling a bunch of data from Excel/Sheet to database. Before storing them to database, I need them to be serialized and verified. So I used RestFramework Serializers, but it's very slow with thousands instances.
My code is here

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.serializers import Serializer

class ChannelSerializer(Serializer):
    raw_channel_link = serializers.CharField(max_length=2048, allow_null=False, allow_blank=False)

    channel_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=512, required=False, allow_null=True, allow_blank=True)
    contact_info = serializers.CharField(max_length=2048, required=False, allow_null=True, allow_blank=True)
    username = serializers.CharField(max_length=512, required=False, allow_null=True, allow_blank=True)
    email = serializers.CharField(max_length=512, required=False, allow_null=True, allow_blank=True)
    phone = serializers.CharField(max_length=16, required=False, allow_null=True, allow_blank=True)

    # DateField but setup CharField for allow_blank without Validation exception
    crawl_date = serializers.CharField(max_length=10, required=False, allow_null=True, allow_blank=True)
    reached_date = serializers.CharField(max_length=10, required=False, allow_null=True, allow_blank=True)
    approval_date = serializers.CharField(max_length=10, required=False, allow_null=True, allow_blank=True)

    error_log = serializers.CharField(required=False)

def create(self, validated_data):
    pass

def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    pass


def get_data():
    return {
        'approval_date': '14/08/2021',
        'channel_link': 'https://www.tiktok.com/@xxxx? 
                       lang=en&is_copy_url=1&is_from_webapp=v2',
        'channel_name': '',
        'contact_info': '',
    'crawl_date': '',
    'email': '03/20/2021',
    'phone': '098905xxxx',
    'raw_channel_link': 'https://www.tiktok.com/@xxx?lang=en&is_copy_url=1&is_from_webapp=v2',
    'reached_date': '',
    'username': '',
    'error_log': '_'
}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in tqdm(range(50000)):
    data = get_data()
    channel = ChannelSerializer(data=data)
    channel.is_valid()
```

It takes almost 2mins for finishing this code.
I taked a look over source code of Serializers class but can't find why it's slow.

Comment: Have you checked how long the API request to TikTok takes?

Comment: I only verify input whether Tiktok link is valid or not. I don't take API request to Tiktok